# Were there errors in this users proof of $\|u-u_U\|_{L^q(U)}\leq C\|Du\|_{L^p(U)}$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, sobolev-spaces

When trying to prove $\forall u\in W^{1,p}(U)$, $1\leq p<n$:
$$\|u-u_U\|_{L^q(U)}\leq C\|Du\|_{L^p(U)}$$
where $q=\frac{np}{n-p}$, and $U$ is bounded, open with $C^1$ boundary.

I came across [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/837863/438235):

(They have $U=B_r$ the $r$-ball)

> Hint: First prove that $$\|u-\overline{u}_{B_r}\|_p\le c\|\nabla u\|_p,\ \forall u\in W^{1,p}(B_r)\tag{1}.$$
>
> You can prove $(1)$ by contradiction and you will need Rellich-Kondrachov theorem. To conclude, you can use Sobolev inequality: $$\|u\|_{p^\star}\le c\|u\|_{1,p},\ \forall\ u \in W^{1,p}(B_r),$$
>
> which will imply that $$\|u-\overline{u}_{B_r}\|_{p^\star}\le c(\|u-\overline{u}_{B_r}\|_p+\|\nabla u\|_p)\le c\|\nabla u\|_p,\ \forall\ u\in W^{1,p}(B_r).$$
>
> Now try to match the constants and you will reach the desired inequality.

Should the last line have, one of these two corrections?

$$\|u-\overline{u}_{B_r}\|_{p^\star}\le c(\|u-\overline{u}_{B_r}\|_p+\|\nabla u\|_p)\le \color{red}{(c^2+c)}\|\nabla u\|_p,\ \forall\ u\in W^{1,p}(B_r).$$

Or

$$\|u-\bar{u}_{B_r}\|_{p^\star}\leq c\|u-\bar{u}_{B_r}\|_p + \|\nabla(u\color{red}{-\bar{u}_{B_r}})\|_p$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient of a constant is zero, no need to insert $\nabla \bar{u}_{B_r}$. In PDE theory it is customary to denote by $c$ or $C$ a constant that may assume different values in the same chain of inequalities. It is a slight abuse of notation, but it would be cumbersome to label each constant like $c_1$, $c_2$,..., $c_{104}$, and so on.

Comment: Ahhh yes. Of course. Many thanks.